# Is it possible to detect what template(s) have been applied to a PowerPoint presentation?

Tags: c#, vsto, powerpoint

I'm trying to write an add-in that checks user presentations for overall consistency against a series of business rules that I'm expecting largely to be defined in a number of masters style the slides a user might be working on. This should work fine if the user has applied a template, but if they have not, I'm unsure how to detect it.

Looking at the object model, neither `Slide.CustomLayout` nor `Presentation.SlideMaster` seem to have a property that mentions the original filename of the master currently in use (the `name` property is identical both before and after a business template has been applied).

Can anyone think of a good way to detect if a template is in use (so I can flag to the user that the first thing they might want to do is use one), or at least find if the template in use is the default one...

Writing the addin in C#, but I suspect this kind of thing will be the same in more or less any office automation language...

Answer (score 0):

Suppose there's a shape of a known name or (better) tagged with a known value on the master slide of the template.  That shape should then appear on the master slide of a presentation once the template containing the master slide has been applied.

Comment: This works, but not ideal, since I don't have control over the templates, so I can't really guarantee that such a shape will be present. It's probably the approach I'll use if I can't find anything more accurate better though.

Comment: The only alternative I can think of is to build some sort of record of each shape on each layout of each master, store details of every feature you need to control, then vet the masters in the users' slides and masters against this "database".  All of which would be ugly, fragile and require major rework whenever the templates changed.  And there are other problems with it.  Let's not go there.  ;-)

Comment: Yeah, that's my suspicion... Most likely I'll need to take a stochastic approach similar to this. That is, have a defined series of tests that probabilify whether the template has been applied (e.g. list of layout and master names) and then flag on that basis, possibly updating the expected list of names once the user has chosen to apply the fix or not. Painful, though...